# Extracting Dictionary Value from a Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a tuple which is basically like this:

```
t=(OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'User'), ('url', '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/User/0006Cx6pIAC')])), ('Name', 'Ben Dams')]),)
```

How do I extract just the 'Name' from the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single-value tuple which contains a dictionary. So just use indexing before accessing a dictionary key:

```
res = t[0]['Name']  # 'Ben Dams'
```